# Ghdl in Ubuntu 13.04

Tags: software-installation, ppa

Just installed Ubuntu 13.04 after formating my laptop, and for some reason I can not install ghdl. After adding the ppa with this command :

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:pgavin/ghdl
```

everything is fine, but when i try do :

```
sudo apt-get install ghdl
```

I get an error saying : `The ghdl package has no available version`.

Any way to solve it?

Comment: 15.04: http://askubuntu.com/questions/655961/use-14-04-application-in-15-04

Answer (score 5):

You need to

```
sudo apt-get update
```

after adding the ppa. Then the installation command should work.