# Use 14.04 application in 15.04

Tags: 14.04, software-installation, 15.04, ppa

I am running 15.04. I need to install [ghdl](https://launchpad.net/~pgavin/+archive/ubuntu/ghdl). However after adding the repository when I do

```
apt-get update
```

I keep getting

```
failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/pgavin/ghdl/ubuntu/dists/vivid/main/binary-i386/Packages
```

Why is this?

Comment: Did you try to contact the PPA maintainer?

Answer (score 2):

There are no packages for 15.04 in this ppa, but the ones for 14.04 (trusty) may work.

You can directly download a deb file from PPA.

Click `View Package details` and download a 32 or 64-bit deb.

[32-bit](https://launchpad.net/~pgavin/+archive/ubuntu/ghdl/+files/ghdl_0.31-1pgavin2~trusty2_i386.deb)

[64-bit](https://launchpad.net/~pgavin/+archive/ubuntu/ghdl/+files/ghdl_0.31-1pgavin2~trusty2_amd64.deb)

Answer (score 1):

As @Pilot6 said, there are no packages for Trusty.

**In this case**, it's not a problem to use the Trusty packages and it's OK to use the `list` file for Trusty packages to get updates. What you need is the installation of some additionally Trusty packages.

Here the example for 32-bit. For 64-bit packages select your download from this sites: [`libgnat-4.8`](http://packages.ubuntu.com/trusty/libgnat-4.8), [`gnat-4.8-base`](http://packages.ubuntu.com/trusty/gnat-4.8-base)

- `libgnat-4.8` (32-bit)

  ```
  cd
  wget http://mirrors.kernel.org/ubuntu/pool/universe/g/gnat-4.8/libgnat-4.8_4.8.2-8ubuntu3_i386.deb
  ```
- `gnat-4.8-base` (32-bit)

  ```
  cd
  wget http://mirrors.kernel.org/ubuntu/pool/universe/g/gnat-4.8/gnat-4.8-base_4.8.2-8ubuntu3_i386.deb
  ```
- Install the deb files

  ```
  sudo dpkg -i ~/Downloads/gnat-4.8-base_4.8.2-8ubuntu3_i386.deb
  sudo dpkg -i ~/Downloads/libgnat-4.8_4.8.2-8ubuntu3_i386.deb
  ```

After that, replace `vivid` with `trusty` in your `list` file:

```
sudo nano /etc/apt/sources.list.d/pgavin-ubuntu-ghdl-vivid.list
```

Or as one-liner

```
sudo sed -i 's/vivid/trusty/' /etc/apt/sources.list.d/pgavin-ubuntu-ghdl-vivid.list
```

and install `ghdl`

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install --reinstall ghdl
```

---

From time to time you should check the PPA for Vivid packages.

Comment: I would not recommend this. But it will work.

Answer (score 1):

**Installation from source is very simple**

```
sudo apt-get install gnat-5
git clone https://github.com/tgingold/ghdl
git checkout v0.33
cd ghdl
./configure --prefix=/usr/local
make
make install
ghdl --version
```

And now you can try the hello world documented at: http://ghdl.readthedocs.io/en/latest/Starting_with_GHDL.html#the-hello-world-program

Tested on Ubuntu 16.04.

Compiling with the GCC backend is harder, but may have advantages like simulation speed. Procedure and trade-off discussed at: https://github.com/tgingold/ghdl/blob/f2b83716c79e7c6123aa9b6215a6dc6ac1c9d83b/BUILD.txt